# Is YAML python like lists not widely supported?

Tags: yaml

I am pretty new to YAML, so I'm sorry if this is super weird. When I have several elements under the same thing, I create lists like this:

```
---
tags: [tag1, tag2, tag3]
---
```

This has worked fine until now, but then I opened my files in another program and it didn't understand the formatting. It read it with the brackets as a part of tag1 and tag3, and wanted me to write them as:

```
---
tags: tag1, tag2, tag3
---
```

I thought the only other way to write list elements in YAML was like this:

```
---
tags:
    -tag1
    -tag2
    -tag3
---
```

Is my first approach wrong, or is it something I don't understand here?

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
---
tags: [tag1, tag2, tag3]
---
```

Is already questionable, as it is a file that contains *two* YAML documents, the second one being empty.

`---` is a *directives end marker* and is pratically used to explicitly start a new YAML document.

As far as your list is concerned, this is valid YAML.

```yaml
---
tags: tag1, tag2, tag3
---
```

is valid YAML, but the value of `tags` is a single scalar with content `tag1, tag2, tag3`. Some tools might want to have it that way and parse the scalar later manually to separate the tags. But as far as YAML is concerned, this is not a list.

```yaml
---
tags:
    -tag1
    -tag2
    -tag3
---
```

is wrong. YAML requires a space after the sequence item indicator, like this:

```
---
tags:
  - tag1
  - tag2
  - tag3
---
```

> It read it with the brackets as a part of tag1 and tag3

Then it doesn't use YAML syntax. Doing this is a violation of the YAML spec.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. I really appreciate it. I thought --- signalled both start and finish, but I see that is wrong. Again, thank you so much!